# Adding items to JComboBox while program is running

Tags: java, user-interface, jcombobox

My program has a GUI where the user first selects a button to load an excel file. Then the content of the excel file is listed in a JTextArea and JComboBox. As you can see in the picture, although the JTextArea contains some texts, JComboBox is empty. I debugged the code and can verify that JComboBox's variable (TheGene) adds the item. In other word, `str` contains AARS, AARS2, ... in each iteration.

[image]

Examples that describe JComboBox statically adds items after the JComboBox is created. I want to add items after running something (when the button's work is finished).

I am using the frame designer of Netbeans, where is automatically generates the following code

```
public class TheFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
  ...
  private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> TheGene;
  private void initComponents() {
    ...
    TheGene = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    TheGene.setMaximumRowCount(20);
    TheGene.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        TheGeneActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    ...
  }
  private void TheGeneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
  {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int n = theFile.getGeneNumberFromFile();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      String str = theFile.getGeneNameFromFile( i );
      TheGene.addItem(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your using the right event. Isn't **TheGene** the name of your JComboBox? Or is that the name of your JButton? Where is the JButton event code?

Comment: Pleas see the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a model for your `JComboBox`like :

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
JComboBox TheGene = new JComboBox( model );
```

and then later with clicking of `Load Gene List` button :

```
private void TheGeneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                       
    model.removeAllElements();               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int n = theFile.getGeneNumberFromFile();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      String str = theFile.getGeneNameFromFile( i );
      model.addElement(str);
   }
}
```

This should make the combo's items populated.

Comment: You should be able to add elements to your model in the action listener of the `Load Gene List` button. Hitting the combobox and updating the model is not a recommended way of doing it.

Comment: Indeed I used your comment's idea and it works. Just want to know what is the purpose of `DefaultComboBoxModel`?

Comment: It serves as a model for the `JComboBox`. I assume you are already aware of MVC design pattern. The View here is `JComboBox` and the model is `DefaultComboBoxModel`, any changes to the model are reflected to the `JCombobox` dropdown list. In other words it enables user to handle changes to data separately from the view i.e. `JComboBox`'s rendering

Comment: As a minor question, assume an item is shown in combobox (X) but the user has not selected that (kind of default item). Then my program doesn't capture that and the `getSelectedItem()` returns null. However, if the user opens the combo and select that item (X), then it returns X in my code. Any way to fix that?

Comment: I assume the `default` item that you see is either the first item in the list after you hit the `Load Gene List` button or you have explicitly set using `setSelectedItem( Object obj)`. If it is the former, you won't get any thing from `getSelectedItem()`, if it is later you should get an object from `getSelectedItem()`. I think you have an action listener for your combo box where the `getSelectedItem()` returns an object selected. If you want to use this somewhere else, store it in a private variable.